# Prestashop - CSV Import page goes to Login and doesn't work

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I'm using PS 1.6.1 and strangely I'm not able to access the CSV Import page. When I click on it, I get redirected to the Sign In page. There, no matter how many times I enter my credentials it keeps bringing me back to the login page. If I enter incorrect details I get the error that Email/Password do not match but if I enter correct details, it keeps loading the login page over and over again without any message.

All other pages are working fine. I've enabled debugging but I don't see any error on any pages. How do I debug this issue?

Comment: Clear browser cookies. If it worked then you have to debug that which code or module is creating cookie for that redirection.

Comment: Yes it did work after clearing session and cookie data. How do I debug this problem? I'm new to prestashop.

Comment: Now delete cookie one by one and if after deleting any cookie, if issue is resolved then that cookie is responsible for the issue. Search that in your website code that from where it is created.